# Display Notification clear notification in android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i am developing application in that i have to receive notification from GCM ,i am successfully receive notification but it have only display recent notification but i want to display all notifications in notification bar and whenever it open i will be gone icon on notification bar these both are not working for me please help me.

my code is given below

```
 @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

     if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

         if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                //sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                sendNotification(msg);
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
     GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}


 mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    Intent myintent = new Intent(this, ReceiveActivity.class);
    myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
    .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
    .bigText(msg))
    .setContentText(msg);

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
            new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    String[] events = new String[6];
    // Sets a title for the Inbox style big view
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Event tracker details:");

    int numMessages = 0;

    // Moves events into the big view
    for (int i=0; i < events.length; i++) {

        inboxStyle.addLine(events[i]);
    }

    mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

    /* Even if the mode is set to "Sound & Vibration" in the phone, 
     * the status code that getRingerMode() returns is RINGER_MODE_NORMAL.
     */
    switch (am.getRingerMode()) 
    {
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
            mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
            break;
        case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
            mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
            break;
        default:
            mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
     }


    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent).setNumber(++numMessages);

    // TO clear notification

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
             .bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID++, mBuilder.build());
```

This worked for me.

Remove last part of code

```
mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
             .bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);
```

Comment: its ok but all notifiacations shows only one message i.e last data only

Comment: where i have to change my logic

Comment: post your onHandle() code too
plz accept answer and upvote it.if it helped